# Swift App Termination removes Kingfisher Disk Cache

Tags: ios, swift, caching, kingfisher

I'm having trouble with my kingfisher cache. The scenario: I save images from URL to a custom kingfisher cache.

When I read the given URL, it tells me that it first fetches the image from memory and after a few seconds, when refreshing, from disk. When I manually close the app and restart, on opening, kingfisher tells me that the cache disk size is for example 20MB. (This is what I expect)

Basically, the cache works perfectly all the time, **except**: When I move the app to the background it remains open for 5-30 minutes, until Apple/iOS kills it (`Terminated due to signal 9`) for memory reasons. When I start the app then, the cache (both memory and disk) is empty! How is that possible? What is the difference between the user and apple killing the application?

Comment: isn't that exactly the sense of a cache? It will be cleaned if there are memory issues? So if you don't want this, you have to save your images in another directory....

Comment: It's better to find why your app getting crash or Terminated due to memory issue. If you are trying to store more than device available memory. Off-course OS will terminate if there is no available memory for your App. First of all solve your issue.

Comment: hey @Chris - that's partially true, but isn't that the reason why kingfisher moves the memory cache to disk? Disk storage shouldn't be impacted by memory issues?

Comment: No, because disk storage is in a temporary directory and will be cleaned up as well

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the clarification, that is perfect to know! Is it possible to move the temporary directory to a more permanent directory?

Comment: yes, this is possible. you can give a directory url like this: ImageCache(name: "test", cacheDirectoryURL: url) -> url could be your documents folder e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this is possible. you can give a directory url like this: ImageCache(name: "test", cacheDirectoryURL: url) -> url could be your documents folder e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Both memory storage and disk storage have default expiration setting. Images in memory storage will expire after 5 minutes from last accessed (or will be removed during an application termination), while it is a week for images in disk storage. You can change this value by:

```
// Memory image expires after 10 minutes.
cache.memoryStorage.config.expiration = .seconds(600)

// Disk image never expires.
cache.diskStorage.config.expiration = .never
```

If you want to override this expiration for a certain image when caching it, pass in with an option:

```
// This image will never expire in memory cache.
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, options: [.memoryCacheExpiration(.never)])
```

The expired memory cache will be purged with a duration of 2 minutes. If you want it happens more frequently:

```
// Check memory clean up every 30 seconds.
cache.memoryStorage.config.cleanInterval = 30
```

[source: Kingfisher Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#set-default-expiration-for-cache)